# Error importing Firebase functions in JavaScript for displaying logged in user's training

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, web, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a website that allows athletes to view their current set training assigned by their coach on the "portalEntrenamientos.html" page. I am using Firebase's Realtime Database to store and retrieve the training data.

However, when I try to import Firebase functions in my JavaScript file "portalEntrenamiento.js", I get a persistent error. Specifically, I receive the following error message:

> Unexpected token '{'. import call expects one or two arguments.

The error points to the first line of code in my "portalEntrenamiento.js" file, which is:

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.20.0/firebase-app.js";
```

I have tried importing Firebase functions using different methods, but none of them seem to work. I suspect that I am missing something in my code, but I'm not sure what it is.

Can anyone provide insights or suggestions on how to resolve this error and achieve my goal of displaying the logged in user's training on the "portalEntrenamientos.html" page? I appreciate any help or guidance.

Below is my "portalEntrenamiento.js" code for reference:

```
    // Import the necessary Firebase functions
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.20.0/firebase-app.js";
    import { getDatabase, onValue, ref, query } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.20.0/firebase-database.js";
    import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.20.0/firebase-auth.js";
    
    // Configure the Firebase app
    const firebaseConfig = {
      // Firebase configuration details here
    };
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const database = getDatabase();
    const auth = getAuth();
    
    // Retrieve the logged in user's training from the Realtime Database
    const nombreAtleta = document.getElementById('nombre-atleta');
    const entrenamientoAsignado = document.getElementById('entrenamiento-asignado');
    
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        onValue(query(ref(database, 'USERS/ATHLETES' + user.uid + '/training')), (snapshot) => {
          const entrenamiento = snapshot.val();
          nombreAtleta.textContent = entrenamiento.atleta;
          entrenamientoAsignado.textContent = entrenamiento.descripcion;
        });
      } else {
        window.location.href = "login.html";
      }
    });
```